# Strange issue with request streaming by Android to node server

Tags: android, node.js, file-upload

Let me explain, We have node server to handle all server related task and our client is web-app and android app.

At the server end, We are using `multer` module to handling multipart-data and `JSZip` module for reading/writing Zip files.

When browser upload any zip file then `multer` process it and store it in tmp folder and then using JSZip module we can easily read out and process data. But same process is followed by Android app then `JSZip` module ignore to read zip file. It's strange behaviour. Even same file is easily uploading by web-client but ignore it when it will upload by android-client.

I have checked (integrity test) zip file by `unzip -t upload-file` command after uploading each client. I found warning

> warning [file-name.zip]:  2 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile

When uploading from android app client.

Can anybody help me out and explain me what's going wrong with request processing in android ?? (I don't have much idea about multipart-data uploading from android )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dump raw data and check both client request. Getting extra "\r\n" from android client. Now it's working when removing both newline and carriage-return.

Thanks! :)